# Load CSV values then search for matches in mysql database and then apply insertion?

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv

I am using python Django and I have a CSV file which contains 4 fields name, abbreviation, address and type of school. I have 3 database table named university, type of university and university-type mapping.I am having a csv list which has name of university I want to compare it with university table present in database and want to find out id corresponding to that name and same process with type of university and find out its id.And then i want to insert those values into university-type mapping.
I am able to read data from CVS using this method but stuck on database search for match:
here is what i am using to read the search:

```
import csv

path = '/home/abi/Downloads'

file=open( path +"university.CSV", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
    t=line[1],line[2]
    print(t)
```

NAME

```
NIT
Pune University
New University
Gujarat Technical  University
Kuwait University - College of Business Administration جامعة الكويت - كلية العلوم الادارية
testuniversity
testuniversity
testuniversity23
testuniversity
Mumbai university
Mumbai university
California University
California University
California University
California University
California University
```

this is the one field in csv

and i have university sql table with field 'name' and i want to compare it CSV name and get the corresponding id from it

```
>>> import csv
>>> import pymysql
>>> import pymysql.cursors 
>>> connection = pymysql.connect(user='root',password='root')

>>> path = '/home/abi/Downloads/'
>>> t=[]
>>> p=[]
>>> file  = open(path +"university_list.csv - university_list.csv.csv","r" )
>>> reader = csv.reader(file)
>>> for line in reader:
...     t=line[0]
...     p=line[3]
...     print t
```

Comment: you can use pymysql to connect mysql and search tables.

Comment: @Frank i use pymysql and it worked but how can i compare my values of csv with database table

Comment: can you give a sample about csv and tables?

Comment: see my edits @Frank i have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do like this:

```
import csv
import pymysql

path = '/home/abi/Downloads'

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='user',                 
passwd='pass', db='db_name', charset='utf8')
cursor1 = conn.cursor()
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor3 = conn.cursor()

file=open( path +"university.CSV", "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
   csv_school_name = line[0]
   csv_school_type = line[3]
   cursor1.execute("select id from schools_names where school_name = s%", csv_school_name)
   corresponding_school_name_id = cursor1.fetchone()
   cursor2.execute("select id from schools_types where school_type = s%", csv_school_type)
   corresponding_school_type_id = cursor2.fetchone()
```

After this you can get school_name_id and school_type_id, then you can insert this two ids into table if you want to do.
I hope this can help you.

you must execute

```
cursor1.execute("select id from schools_names where school_name = s%", csv_school_name)
```

ont time, then use fetchone(), if you use

```
school_id = cursor1.execute("select id from schools_names where school_name = s%", csv_school_name)
```

you will get count of table.

Comment: it worked frank but it is showing total count of school table  instead of id that is what I am checking at the moment...thanks a lot solved some of my purpose

Comment: sorry to disturb u again I m using your query but it is outputting some garbage value in output...0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 so, is it happening because some of the school names are in Arabic?